# Simple Highchart works as seperate .js file, but not in view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm new to Highcharts, and so far have only have had success getting my test chart to display when it's saved in a seperate .js file. The total highcharts_weight.js code is:

```
$(function () { 
    var weightchart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: "weight_chart",
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'weight loss history'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%e %b'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Weight'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Weight loss history',
            data: [[Date.UTC(2013, 1, 1), 87.2],[Date.UTC(2013, 0, 1), 90.2]]
        }]
    });
});
```

That shows up fine on my webpage.

But, if I try putting the code somewhere else, and change the chart name in the .js file, nothing shows up except a blank space where the chart should be.
I've tried putting this code inside  brackets in my root header in application.html.erb and inside  brackets in the partial I want to use to render this table in, but then nothing shows up. Right now, I have it in application.html.erb, in the header,

```
<script>
        $(function () { 
            var weightchart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: "weight_chart",
                    type: 'line'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'weight loss history'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                        day: '%e %b'
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Weight'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Weight loss history',
                    data: [[Date.UTC(2013, 1, 1), 87.2],[Date.UTC(2013, 0, 1), 90.2]]
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: It's no error - if you didn't know you should be looking at a chart instead of nothing, there's no indication of anything going wrong. Looking at the log, everything loads correctly, the web page displays without a compiling error.

Comment: Have you put any breakpoints to know if your code actually runs?

Comment: I'm not sure where to put any breakpoints. The web page compiles, and the chart displays when I import it from a .js file. When I wrap the exact same code from the .js file in <script> tags in a view, it doesn't show up.

Comment: No issues were found in the above code. Check if the path to the highcharts library js is included correctly.

Comment: With wrong path, including external file won't display chart too. @Coco13 - are you sure you have no error in javascript console? If you put `console.log('sth');` before and after: `var weightchart = new Highchart.Chart({...});` - is it displayed in console?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run the chart soon after your DOM is constructed then better use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({})
 });
```

this may solve the problem.

Comment: Is there any specific difference between: `$(document).ready(function() {})` and `$(function() {})`? I thought it's the same.

Comment: Actually I always use $(document).ready(). I thought there might be some difference, checked just now there is no difference between both.